# java code to compute some multiple of a number?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am using Math.PI in my example, so it is a double. It is a simple code but there is a bit I am not sure how to do:

I want the code to calculate the fundamental period `X` of a `sin` or `cos` function with a multiplier value `a` given by the user. The `n` value is initialized at `n=1` and is an integer value.

If the result of `(2 * pi * n)/a = X` is lower than `pi` then `n` should increment, and it should keep going until that number is a multiple of `pi`, then print the result.

Just to clarify: `a` is a multiplier of `x` which goes in the function `sin` or `cos` like this:

`cos(ax)`

`sin(ax)`

The bit I am having the trouble with is working out whether the number is a multiple of `pi` (provided it's already greater than `pi`, that is).

This is about as far as I got and it's incomplete.

```
 public void printSinusoidalPeriod(double multiplier /* this would be `a` */){

    double pi=Math.PI;

    double p = (2 * pi * (double) n) / multiplier;

    while(p<pi){

        if(n%pi==0){

            n=n+1;
            System.out.println(n);
                            p = (2 * pi * (double) n) / multiplier;
        }
    }
    p= (double)Math.round(p * 100) / 100;


    System.out.println("period of function is = " + p + " and n = " + n);
}
```

It seems like it's not going into the if statement and getting caught in the while loop

Comment: If I understand your algorithm correctly, it will always stop at `n=a/2`.

Comment: that wouldn't work for a=3 or a=1 and this is a multiple of x (I will try to clear it up in the question so that the question makes more sense

Comment: What is the question, exactly?  The period of `cos(ax)` is `2*Pi/a`, I don't think you need an algorithm to calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's how I did it in the end, with the help of the suggestions here.

```
public void printSinusoidalPeriod(double a){

    double pi=Math.PI;
    double p=m*pi;

    while(n<a/2){

        if((double)Math.round((n*pi)%pi)!=0.01){

            n=n+1;

            m = (int) Math.round(((2 * (double) n) / a));
            p= (double)Math.round(m * pi * 100) / 100;
            p=p*n;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("period of function is = " + p + " and n = " + n);
    System.out.println("Check: p/n = " + p/n);
}
```

Please let me know if you can spot any problems with the logic. I have not gone through many possibities yet, but the ones I did, looked okay to me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly

```
 while((2 * pi * n)/a)<pi)
    {
        if(!(n%pi==0))
        {
            n++;
            }
    }
```

multiple of y is the part you need to figure out yourself. but this should help you with the logic, If I have understood u correctly.

Comment: (2*pi*n) is your X, I havent touched it so it will make more sense to you. Would have been helpful if you added your attempted code as well.

Comment: the multiple bit is the bit i'm struggling with. I was hoping to get help with that. I will see about adding some code.

Comment: Keep in mind this is double (floating) point, you may not land on an exact multiple.  You'll want something like `(n%pi < GOOD_ENOUGH)` where `GOOD_ENOUGH` might be, just as an example, `0.0000001`.  I'll let others debate proper values.  There are other complications if the period is very small - so are you comfortable with the edge-cases of your expected functions?

Comment: Ah this makes sense now! I had no idea what you were talking about before... @Achilles. Richard I don't need it to be precise but I wouldn't want to miss what should be in the boundary so I think I will try your example thanks for the tip! Will report back!

Comment: ok my edit is as above I think you are onto some @richard but I wasmn't sure how to get it to work

Comment: @Magpie - see Keith Randall's comment directly to your question - isn't this is simple expression?  Why the looping/algorithm?  Are we completely misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish?  I think you need to clarify that before going any further.

Comment: Oh I assumed he was being sarcastic when I saw that but I see what you mean now. To be honest, it could be a pointless exercise, but the motivation behind it is in wanting to find something to apply to other periodic functions later on.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, I had to solve a similar problem to this before using php. Not sure what the correct syntax is for javascript but maybe you should keep a counter that continues until (x/pi) is an integer which would indicate it is a multiple of pi..

I know this isn't the correct code but something like:

```
    while (!isint(x/pi)) {
    x++;
    }
    if (isint(x/pi)) {
    //CODE TO EXECUTE
    }
```

Comment: whooooooops... can't the logic still transfer though?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be calculating when

```
(2 * pi * n)/a = m * pi where m is some integer multiple.
```

so

```
2 * pi * n = m * pi * a

2 * n = m * a

n = m * a / 2
```

You other constraint is

(2 * pi * n)/a < pi

so

```
2 * pi * n < pi * a
2 * n < a
n < a / 2;
```

For both equations to be true, m must be an integer less than 1, but since you are starting at 1 for n it will never be true.